# Spatial join with overlapping polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I have a dataset with two layers: a Planned Projects polygon layer and Roads represented by lines. The lines intersect one another, the Planned Projects polygons overlap.
Using a spatial join that matched roads that are "within" the polygons, I got a copy of the
Roads dataset which includes columns for any overlapping Projects.

The problem is:

As the polygons overlap, some line segments are matched to multiple polygons.

In the image below, the red segments of the road are (correctly) not matched to any polygon; the green segments are (correctly) matched to one polygon, and the blue segments are incorrectly matched to two polygons and only include data for one of the two overlapping project polygons (in this case, they are matched to the horizontal polygon).

[image]

I would like for the vertical segments to be matched with the vertical polygons and horizontal segments matched with the horizontal polygon.

How would I do this using ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Change your join_operation from one-to-one to one-to-many, this will duplicate the line as many times as the relation exists.
2. You can use the field mapping in a smarter way and concatenate the values, a blog on this technique is found [here](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/more-adventures-in-overlay-spatial-join-and-the-field-map/).